# Django. How to create a new instance of a model from views.py with an image field in the model

Tags: python, django, django-models, instance, imagefield

I am trying to create a new instance of a model that has an image field in it. I take a PDF from a form and convert it to a png file format and am now trying to save the png image to a model data base but get the error 'PngImageFile' object has no attribute '_committed'. I know you cant save an image directly to a data base but i'm wondering how can you save the image to the media folder and save the image url path to the image in the data base? Help greatly appreciated.

This is my form to take in the PDF (forms.py)

```
class DrawingPDFForm(forms.Form):
    drawing_name = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    file = forms.FileField()
```

This is my view to convert PDF to PNG and then create new instance of model to save to database(views.py)

```
def upload_drawings(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form  = DrawingPDFForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        drawing_name = request.POST['drawing_name']
        file = request.FILES['file']
        pdf_byt = file.read()
        pdf_content = BytesIO(pdf_byt) 
        pdf_content.seek(0)
        pdf_converted = convert_from_bytes(pdf_content.read(),    poppler_path=r"C:\Python\Python\Programs\plant_locator\poppler\poppler-23.07.0\Library\bin")
        buffer = BytesIO()
        pdf_converted[0].save(buffer, 'png')
        png_byt = buffer.getvalue()
        my_string = base64.b64encode(png_byt)
        pdf_png_byt_decode = base64.b64decode(my_string)
        png = Image.open(BytesIO(pdf_png_byt_decode))
        drawing = Drawing.objects.create(drawing_name=drawing_name, drawing=png)#error occurs here as #expected
        drawing.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/upload_drawings')
    else:
        form  = DrawingPDFForm()
    return render(request, 'upload_drawings.html', {'form':form})
```

This is my model I am trying to create a new instance of (models.py)

```
from django.db import models


class Drawing(models.Model):
    drawing_name = models.CharField('Drawing Name', max_length=50)
    drawing = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="images/")
    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.drawing_name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is what comes to my mind

in your "url.py" file add the following line at the end of your "urlpatterns":

```
from djano.conf import settings
from django .conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

and now you should modify your view to save image to the media folder and store the image path in the model:

```
from django.core.files.uploadedfile import SimpleUploadedFile
import os

def upload_drawings(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form  = DrawingPDFForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        drawing_name = request.POST['drawing_name']
        file = request.FILES['file']
        
        # Convert PDF to PNG
        pdf_byt = file.read()
        pdf_content = BytesIO(pdf_byt) 
        pdf_content.seek(0)
        pdf_converted = convert_from_bytes(pdf_content.read(), poppler_path=r"C:\Python\Python\Programs\plant_locator\poppler\poppler-23.07.0\Library\bin")
        buffer = BytesIO()
        pdf_converted[0].save(buffer, 'png')
        
        # Save PNG to the media folder
        png_byt = buffer.getvalue()
        drawing_path = os.path.join('images', f'{drawing_name}.png')
        drawing_file = SimpleUploadedFile(drawing_path, png_byt, content_type='image/png')
        
        # Create and save the Drawing instance
        drawing = Drawing.objects.create(drawing_name=drawing_name, drawing=drawing_file)
        
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/upload_drawings')
    else:
        form = DrawingPDFForm()
        
    return render(request, 'upload_drawings.html', {'form': form})
```

and make sure you have configured the media settings in your django project:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: You are a legend. This has been bugging me for days